# uses permission Shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

devs, in my android application I'm using **shared preferences**,
my question is: do I need to add any special user permission in the file *AndroidManifest.xml*?

Comment: Always make sure you read the android developer's documentation guide. And you should have tried to use Shared Preferences first and if it doesn't work, you then post your question here.

Comment: @Noah **1** I read the android developer's documentation guide, they didn't mention any uses permission, but I just want to make sure that I'm in the right way  
**2** I've already used to it if you understand the question I posted it

Comment: @Noah I asked a good question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69384158/how-obfuscation-android-app-bundle-works)
can you answer a good answer on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't need to add any permission either in your AndroidManifest.xml nor request any runtime permission since shared preferences xml file is stored in your app folder.

Answer (score 1):

No you don't have to.
Instead of asking this question(with answer yes/no), You should be posting the error that you are getting. This way people will be able to solve your problem.

Comment: I haven't any errors i just want to be sure that's all , If you just answer with yes or no this will be more helpful for me