# how obfuscation android app Bundle works?

Tags: sharedpreferences, proguard

devs , I know that Obfuscation is about renames the remaining classes, fields, and methods using short meaningless names . ...
is there any difference between Obfuscation a bundle (.aab) and Obfuscation an apk (.apk) ?